# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter - .NET Error

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

I have been refactoring one of my old MSSQL Connection helper library and I got the following error:

> Error CS7036  There is no
> argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter
> 'errorMsg' of 'ErrorEventArg.ErrorEventArg(string,
> string)'  MSSQLTest   C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MSSQLTest\MSSQLTest\MSSQLConnection.cs   61

This is my code so far:

**MSSQLConnection.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading;

namespace MSSQLTest
{
    public class ErrorEventArg : EventArgs
    {
        public string ErrorMsg { get; set; }
        public string LastQuery { get; set; }

        public ErrorEventArg(string errorMsg, string lastQuery)
        {
            ErrorMsg = errorMsg;
            LastQuery = lastQuery;
        }
    }

    public class MSSQLConnection
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Private class objects.
        /// </summary>
        private SqlConnection sqlConnection;
        private int sqlCommandTimeout;
        private string lastQuery = string.Empty;

        /// <summary>
        /// Public event related objects & handler.
        /// </summary>
        public event ErrorHandler OnError;
        public delegate void ErrorHandler(MSSQLConnection sender, ErrorEventArg e);

        /// <summary>
        /// Class constructor.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sqlConnection"></param>
        /// <param name="sqlCommandTimeout"></param>
        public MSSQLConnection(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Int32 sqlCommandTimeout = 120)
        {
            if (null == sqlConnection)
                throw new Exception("Invalid MSSQL Database Conection Handle");

            if (sqlConnection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                throw new Exception("MSSQL Database Connection Is Not Open");

            this.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
            this.sqlCommandTimeout = sqlCommandTimeout;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Helper method to emit a database error to event subscribers.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="errorMsg"></param>
        internal void EmitError(String errorMsg)
        {
            var errorDelegate = OnError;
            if (errorDelegate != null)
            {
                errorDelegate(this, new ErrorEventArg() // Line #61
                {
                    ErrorMsg = errorMsg,
                    LastQuery = lastQuery
                });
            }
        }
        
        /// rest of the code snipped
    }
}
```

What does this error means & how do I fix it? I've not seen this error before...

Comment: You have a 2 parameter constructor, why not use that i.e. `new ErrorEventArg(errorMsg,lastQuery)`?

Comment: @pm100 chill man, I asked that question three and a half years ago, roughly around the time I joined SO. I clearly didn't have 11k rep then nor the understanding in C# / general programming stuff that I have now. Also, I am predominantly a PHP developer and I "dabble" in C#, it's not my forte.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have a constructor which takes 2 parameters. You should write something like:

```
new ErrorEventArg(errorMsv, lastQuery)
```

It's less code and easier to read.

**EDIT**

Or, in order for your way to work, you can try writing a default constructor for ErrorEventArg which would have no parameters, like this:

```
public ErrorEventArg() {}
```

Answer (score 29):

In the constructor of

```
public class ErrorEventArg : EventArgs
```

you have to add "base" as follows:

```
public ErrorEventArg(string errorMsg, string lastQuery) : base (string errorMsg, string lastQuery)
{
    ErrorMsg = errorMsg;
    LastQuery = lastQuery;
}
```

Comment: Isn't `base` supposed to take parameters of current constructor like `constructor : base(errorMsg, lastQuery)` instead of redefining like `constructor : base(string errorMsg, string lastQuery)`?

Comment: Great clarification, thank you.

Answer (score 8):

I got the same error but it was due to me not creating a default constructor.  If you haven't already tried that, create the default constructor like this:

```
public TestClass()
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I received this same error in the following Linq statement regarding DailyReport.  The problem was that DailyReport had no default constructor.  Apparently, it instantiates the object before populating the properties.

```
var sums = reports
    .GroupBy(r => r.CountryRegion)
    .Select(cr => new DailyReport
    {
        CountryRegion = cr.Key,
        ProvinceState = "All",
        RecordDate = cr.First().RecordDate,
        Confirmed = cr.Sum(c => c.Confirmed),
        Recovered = cr.Sum(c => c.Recovered),
        Deaths = cr.Sum(c => c.Deaths)
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when one of my properties that was required for the constructor was not public.  Make sure all the parameters in the constructor go to properties that are public if this is the case:

using statements
namespace someNamespace

```
public class ExampleClass {

  //Properties - one is not visible to the class calling the constructor
  public string Property1 { get; set; }
  string Property2 { get; set; }

   //Constructor
   public ExampleClass(string property1, string property2)
  {
     this.Property1 = property1;
     this.Property2 = property2;  //this caused that error for me
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this error message when attempting to build a solution where another developer had removed the parameter from a constructor (there was no inheritance going on), but the old Assembly was in the GAC.

Once I removed it from the GAC, it was able to build using the new code successfully.

Answer (score -1):

```
public ErrorEventArg(string errorMsg, string lastQuery)
    : base (errorMsg, lastQuery)
{
    ErrorMsg = errorMsg;
    LastQuery = lastQuery;
}
```

to call base constructor the parameters of sub class and base class must be same.

Comment: They don't have to be the same. Static methods for example are allowed to be called before the value is passed to the base class, eg `public ErrorEventArg(int errorNumber, string lastQuery)
    : base (GetErrorMsgFromNumber(errorNumber), lastQuery)` where GetErrorMsgFromNumber would consume an int and return a string.