# CS7036 C# WinForm There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following error

> CS7036 C# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required
>   formal parameter 'dt' 'Cadbury_Chocolate.Cadbury_Chocolate(Cart)'

Chocolate Brand List.cs

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   new Cadbury_Chocolate().Show();
}
```

Cadbury_Chocolate.cs

```
public partial class Cadbury_Chocolate : Form
{
    Cart dtGrid;

    public Cadbury_Chocolate(Cart dt)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.dtGrid = dt;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dtGrid.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(label1,label2); 
    }
}
```

Cart.cs

```
public partial class Cart : Form
{
    public Cart()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33607188/5228202

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the class constructor `Cadbury_Chocolate()` in this line `new Cadbury_Chocolate().Show();` but you have only defined a constructor that take one argument of type `Cart` which is `Cadbury_Chocolate(Cart dt)`.

Consider either:

1. Adding/defining another constructor with no parameters `Cadbury_Chocolate()`.
2. Adjust your class instantiation by providing a `Cart` parameter to the already defined constructor `Cadbury_Chocolate(Cart dt)`.

You may want to read about [using constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors)

The mentioned error was already answered here: [There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter - .NET Error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33607188/5228202)

Answer (score 0):

You're not providing the required argument "Cart dt".

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     new Cadbury_Chocolate(cart).Show();
}
```

Replace "cart" with your cart reference.

Comment: It shows   #CS0119 'Cart' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Comment: Because you're trying to pass the type - Cart, instead of already initialized form of type Cart. Is Cart your starting form? If this is the case you should first pass its reference to Chocolate Brand List and then from there to Cadbury_Chocolate. In any case, you probably need a field that holds the reference to Cart form. Read more about constructors, Microsoft has very good explanation and examples in their "Constructors" documentation page.