# how to add return value in xamarin picker option

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

hey i want to know how i can return a value in picker option.
this is my code

```
namespace App1
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {  
       List<courses> myData = new List<courses>();

        public MainPage()
        {
          InitializeComponent();
          // i dont want to use This its working fine 
          MainPicker.Items.Add("String");
     
          // Currently using this in my app but now i want when i select course name from picker option then picker should automatically select key behind the course name so i can generate key using button.

          myData.Add(new Courses
          {
             Course= "ABC",
             Key= "Custom Key"
          });

           MainPicker.ItemsSource = myData;
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           richbox.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(this.AES_Encrypt(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(hardwareid.Text + "," + MainPicker.SelectedItem), "Custom Key"));
        }

          //Now here picker showing course name but its not generating correct key when i click button
        private void MainPicker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           var item = MainPicker.Items[MainPicker.SelectedIndex];
        }
     }
 }
```

XAML code:

```
<Picker Title="Choose a Course"  ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Course}"  SelectedIndexChanged="MainPicker_SelectedIndexChanged"  x:Name="MainPicker">  </Picker>
```

Using **`AES265`** All are working fine but stuck on key value should be return with **`hardwareid.Text`** both when i click button, I dont mention encryption and decryption code here all other are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just showed you how to do this in your previous question

```
var key = ((Courses)MainPicker.SelectedItem).Key;
```

Then the line you’re having problems with becomes

```
richbox.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(this.AES_Encrypt(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(hardwareid.Text + "," + key), "Custom Key"));
```

Comment: still not getting the key value with selecteditem.

Comment: its generating key but not with that one which is already mention in (myData.Add)

Comment: Does SelectedItem contain the correct Courses object?

Comment: yeah its correct but still not getting correct key normally works with this MainPicker.Items.Add("Key");

Comment: That doesn’t make any sense.  If SelectedItem contains the correct Courses object with the correct course and key value, then how is it not returning the correct Key value?  How are you validating that the correct key is being used?

Comment: yeah key is correct but still not working i tired every possible concept, can you please check my code above if something is wrong in XAML?

Comment: New One :

var key = ((Courses)MainPicker.SelectedItem).Key;

Previous One
 ( var item = MainPicker.Items[MainPicker.SelectedIndex]; )

result is same with mydata.add

Comment: I have no idea what “key is correct but still not working” means.  You need to describe what the problem is or why you think it is not working.

Comment: Can you please tell me about this error ?

There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'Name' of 'Courses.Courses(string, string)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33607188/there-is-no-argument-given-that-corresponds-to-the-required-formal-parameter

Comment: thanks for this its solved but when i put any text in hardwaretextbox and choose course from picker menu after that richbox returns this result  : ABC.APP.Courses when i click generate button it should return key and hardware together.

Comment: i removed all the encryption now i just testing textbox with picker and richbox with button generation.

Comment: `hardwareid.Text + "," + MainPicker.SelectedItem` - `SelectedItem` is a **Courses** object.  If you want to use just the **Key** then you should use the `Key` property of that object

Comment: how to do this ? can you please tell me im sorry for asking many questions im beginner i hope you understand :)

Comment: That is literally the answer you’re commenting on.  It shows how to get just the Key from SelectedValue

Comment: im not getting you properly just write that code for me please :)

Comment: can you write that code for me ?

Comment: See my last edit

Comment: thank you soo much now its working we have to just put that code in button property not in the Picker property.

Comment: Hi @DedSec,  please mark the useful answer as answered so that it will help others who have similar problems. Thanks in advance.